# Force WiFi to send data when WiFi and Mobile are available

Tags: android, android-networking

In my app I have data which I want to send only if wi-fi is avaliable.
I can check if wi-fi or mobile data is avaliable, but how do I hadle situation **when both wi-fi and mobile data is active**?  How do I force using wi-fi in this case?

```
private static void logNetworkState() {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    String logStr = "Network state: ";

    if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
        logStr+= " wi-fi avalibale;";
    }
    if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
        logStr+= " mobile network avaliable";
    }
    log(logStr);
}
```

Comment: why do u have such requirement ?

Comment: @MohitSharma I want to send large data only via wi-fi, and text data via mobile or wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

If both are active by default the data is routed through WI-FI. But again it depends on underlying network implementation.

Normally i use **connectivymanager.startusingnetworkfeature()** to force it to use mobile data. again the parameters of above method are implementation specific

Answer (score 0):

By default as my experience when you have both data is transferred via wifi only . But if in case u want to do visa-versa this method may help you  **setNetworkPreference** .

Answer (score 0):

To direct all the network requests from your app to an external Wi-Fi device, call `ConnectivityManager#setProcessDefaultNetwork` on Lollipop devices, and on Marshmallow call `ConnectivityManager#bindProcessToNetwork` instead, which is a direct API replacement.

Check this blog post : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html